# Uncaught MongoError: unrecognized field 'allowDiskUsage'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I installed 2.5.5 so that I can try the new "$out" operator to create new collections with aggregation results. My node adapter is mongodb@1.3.23. I don't have "allowDiskUsage" in my code, but I get this error:

```
Uncaught MongoError: unrecognized field 'allowDiskUsage'
```

What do I need to do to update my project to run 2.5.5?

Answer (score 1):

From a simple test on the same driver version I do not see the same results:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, db) {
  if (!err) {

    db.collection('data', function(err, collection) {
      if (!err) {

        collection.aggregate([
          {$out: "another" },
        ],function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          db.close();
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

There is an option for `allowDiskUse` that can be passed to the `runCommand` call to [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/aggregate/), but this does not directly have an impact on the [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline operator, as it is intended for allowing the stages to use disk storage rather than memory alone. The usage of $out as you will be aware is to put the results in an *output* collection rather than return a cursor object.

If the same code used by itself is causing the same problem, you should check your installed driver version. As of 1.3.23 with a MongoDB 2.5.5 server, this code works as expected.

If this code passes, then there is likely some call or overriding module in your project that is implementing the option you specify in the error.